# Conditional expectation given we roll an unbiased die

Tags: probability

> Roll an unbiased die successively and call $X$ and $Y$ denote the
> rolls necessary to obtain a 6 and a 5 , respectively. Compute
> $E(X|Y=5)$. In general, can you compute $E(X|Y=y)$?

### Try

The event $X|Y=5$ is also geometric but we have cases.

before the fifth roll notice that $X$ is still geometric with parameter $p=1/6$ since neither 5 or a 6 have occured. but, after the fifth roll, a 6 has shown up so we only have 5 number to pick from and thus after thus we have a geometric rv with parameter $p' = \frac{1}{5}$. Therefore

$$ E(X|Y=5) = 6 + 5 = 11 $$

is this correct?

Comment: maybe I interpret wrongly: I thought the question allow you to have $X < Y$, i.e. obtain the first $6$ before the first $5$. If you must have the $5$ first, then the calculation is fine, which should be $y + 6$. If not, you need to consider the first $y-1$ rolls as well (which are non-$5$, and thus is like $\text{Geometric}(1/5)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key fact here is that Geometric Distributions are memory-less.

$E(X|Y=5) = E(Y=5) + E(X) = 5 + \frac{1}{p_X} = 5+6 = 11$.

So, yes your reasoning is correct.